# Fragment уплывает под Actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, actionbar

При попытке загрузить фрагмент в контейнер часть фрагмента уплывает под табы.Как решить даную проблему? Извиняюсь за то что уже обращялся с таким вопросом но проблема с тех пор так и не решилась.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

app_bar.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.fragments.MusContent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

Content.java

```
package com.example.kombo.eplog.fragments;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.kombo.eplog.R;


public class MusContent extends Fragment {

    private int COUNT_OF_TABS=2;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public MusContent() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mus_content, container, false);
        View content=(View) container.getParent();
        appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout)content.findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        tabLayout=new TabLayout(getActivity());
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        appBarLayout.addView(tabLayout);

        viewPager=(ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        VpAdapter pagerAdapter=new VpAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        appBarLayout.removeView(tabLayout);
    }

    public class VpAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public VpAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0: return new FragmentMusic();
                case 1: return new FragmentAlbums();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return COUNT_OF_TABS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: return getResources().getString(R.string.music_str);
                case 1: return getResources().getString(R.string.albums_str);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: добавьте свою разметку.

Comment: что то в разметке я не вижу `tabLayout`

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" добавьте либо в include либо в саму разметку content_main.xml

Comment: Пробывал, не помогло

Comment: А нет Помогло. Теперь контент видно полностью. Только появилась новая проблема: теперь увеличился отступ сверху и между кнопкой и табами, пробел приб. 20dp хотя этого быть вроде как не должно